# vim: code complete using omnifunc error for python

Tags: python, vim

I want to use code complete for python. I generate tags and set its path in `.vimrc` like this:

```
set tags=/home/abc/python.tags
```

if I comment "filetype plugin on",  when I press c-x c-o vim will tell me:

> option omnifunc is not set

However, if I add `filetype plugin on` in `.vimrc`, when I press `C-x C-o` vim will exit and tell me:

> Import error: No module named site.

What can I do to use code complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Import error: No module named site.`

You need set env variables `PYTHONPATH` correctly.

Comment: I know what's the problem: I install a new python but didn't compile vim with new python.